# Shortcode putting html such as <img>

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, validation, sanitization

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(

        'path' => 'https://s.w.org/about/images/logos/wordpress-logo-simplified-rgb.png'

    ), $atts);
```

The above is a part of the shortcode. In Wordpress text editor this shortcode is produced like this →

```
[theimg  path=""]
```

the inverted comma needs to have the image URL of this →

[theimg  path="https://geordiebiker.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/audrey-marnay-longchamp-commando-drive-side.jpg"]

## Problem:

when we are in the visual mode of the text editor and we put an image URL in those commas it actually pulls the image, not URL. I have done a [gif to explain this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/sitepoint007/_shortcodeissue.gif).

I believe that this missing sanitization such as esc_url etc, but I do not know the exact fix.

**Update:**
if I put only the URL in the shortcode, the editor adds the `<img src="">` tags?

P.S.→  the image can't be uploaded here as it was above 2MB.

## Update 11 Jan 2018

```
$output = '<div class="someclasss">';

        $output .= '<img class="someclass1" src="'.$atts['simg'].'" alt="' .$caption. '" >';

    $output .= '<i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i>';

$output .= '</div>';

return $output;
```

The above way the output is rendered in the browser.

Finally, in the browser, it will appear like this:

```
<img src="<img src="http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/84/6074239-free-image.jpg" />">
```

Is there a way we can ensure that in the  `src="'.$atts['path'].'"` this part:

```
.$atts['simg'].
```

only takes URL and strips out everything?

Comment: Does the shortcode work? The WYSIWYG editor may have JavaScript rules that render the image, but that doesn't mean it breaks the functionality of the shortcode.

Comment: Yes, if we go and put the image in text mode(not in the visual mode) than it works. when we do this in the visual mode and then see this in text mode it gives this → `[theimg  path="<img src="https://geordiebiker.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/audrey-marnay-longchamp-commando-drive-side.jpg" />"]
` that means it generates whole HTML not just URL thats the issue.

Comment: In a sense, it actually breaks the functionality when we use visual tab to render shortcode.

Comment: You mean even if you put only the URL in the shortcode, the editor will add the `<img>` tags?

Comment: Yes, you are right Jack that what I have shown in that [gif](https://s3.amazonaws.com/sitepoint007/_shortcodeissue.gif).

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is most likely intended, and can be disabled. However it might break other features too. There are a couple of workarounds, that you can try.

### Break the Image URL and File Name

You can pass the arguments to your shortcode in the following way:

```
[theimg 
    path="https://s.w.org/about/images/logos/" 
    filename="wordpress-logo-simplified-rgb.png"
]
```

This will prevent the editor from parsing the URL, but you can get the values and put them together in your PHP code.

### Use `preg_match()`

So, the editor converts the URL to a full HTML image? Fine, let him do it. After the editor passed the full image to the shortcode, we can use a `preg_match` in our PHP code to extract the URL:

```
preg_match( '@src="([^"]+)"@' , $img, $match );
```

This will parse the `$img` content and return the `src` of the `<img>` tag.

Comment: thanks, let me try implementing this, and I will update you on success or challenges if any.

Comment: Wordpress release security updates like this [one](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/23/changes-to-the-shortcode-api/). Could this be the case that the shortcode is not built in such a way that is considered secure? that's the reason that image is not taken as a URL, but through HTML like src?

Comment: Security is usually implemented in the server level, but your problem is happening in the front-end because of the editor's behavior. I don't think this is a security issue. The editor is just trying to be smart and converting the URLs to actual images automatically.

Comment: Here is the full file of the [shortcode](https://s3.amazonaws.com/sitepoint007/shortcode.php); I didn't post the full code because it was not needed + I didn't want the whole code to be indexed later and create issues in future. can you guide me where should I use this in my shortcode: `preg_match( '@src="([^"]+)"@' , $img, $match );`

Comment: #2 the actual user will have to break the URL in shortcode like this: [theimg  path="https://geordiebiker.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/" filename="audrey-marnay-longchamp-commando-drive-side.jpg"]. because this is `[theimg 
    path="https://s.w.org/about/images/logos/" 
    filename="wordpress-logo-simplified-rgb.png"
]` a default image setting, the images needs to be changed later thats what the utility of shortcode is.

Comment: You just need to add the `preg_match( ... )` before the `$url = filter_var ( ... )` and then use `$matches[0]` instead of `$atts['path']`.

Comment: can you also look into the issue and answer my question#2.

Comment: I don't understand the second issue. What is it? Assuming you change your shortcode to break the URL, you can get the full URL by using `$url = $atts['path'] . $atts['filename']`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71438/discussion-between-the-wp-novice-and-jack-johansson).

Comment: Yes, assuming that is implemented: 
what I am trying to say is this: 
Previously we were putting URL in the shortcode(Visual editor) like this: 
`[theimg path="https://geordiebiker.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/audrey-marnay-longchamp-commando-drive-side.jpg"]`, 

but now we have to put it like this → 
`[theimg  path="https://geordiebiker.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/" filename="audrey-marnay-longchamp-commando-drive-side.jpg"]` 

Right?
If that's true then, in that case, wouldn't that be cumbersome for a layman user to break the image into 2 parts?

Comment: Johanson, Did you happened to get a chance to look at my last message? Additionally, the image URL will not be always same. so it is not just a one URL case.

Comment: In that case this wouldn't work.  You can try and disable this feature from TinyMCE. Further information can be found [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/url-handling/).

Comment: I have updated my question with some additional information. May be fixing that we can get to the solution w/o altering TinyMCE